# How to android unit test and mock a static method

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

Hi I really hope you can help me, I feel like I've been pulling my hair out for days.

I'm trying to write unit tests for a method A. Method A calls a static method B. I want to mock static method B.

I know this has been asked before, but I feel Android has matured since then, and there must be a way to do such a simple task without re-writing the methods I want to test.

Here is an example, first the method I want to test:

```
public String getUserName(Context context, HelperUtils helper) {
    if(helper == null){
        helper = new HelperUtils();
    }
    int currentUserId = helper.fetchUsernameFromInternet(context);

    if (currentUserId == 1) {
        return "Bob";
    } else {
        return "Unknown";
    }
}
```

Next the static method I want to mock:

```
public class HelperUtils {
    public static int fetchUsernameFromInternet(Context context) {
        int userid = 0;

        Log.i("HelperUtils ", "hello");

        return userid;
    }
}
```

In other languages this is so easy but I just can't make it work in Android. 
I've tried Mockito, but it appears static methods aren't supported

```
HelperUtils helper = Mockito.mock(HelperUtils.class);
Mockito.when(helper.fetchUsernameFromInternet(getContext())).thenReturn(1);
```

This errors

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException

I've tried Powermock but I'm not completely sure this is supported by Android. I managed to get powermock running using androidCompile in my gradle file but I get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebugAndroidTest'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

Not to mention `PowerMockito.mockStatic(HelperUtils.class);` Doesn't return anything, so I don't know what to pass into my getUsername method!

Any help would be so very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't have a proper answer, but I recently went around singletons and static classes by replacing them with a service locator pattern. It made them easily testable and took a few minutes for each class to convert.

Comment: I don't know so much about testing in other languages, but in Java, `static` is the enemy of testing.

Comment: You might want to have a look at PowerMock (https://github.com/jayway/powermock). It's a test framework that allows you to test difficult cases.

Comment: PowerMockito just gives PowerMock Mockito-flavored API, technically they both do the same

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Static methods aren't related to any object - your `helper.fetchUsernameFromInternet(...)` is the same (but a bit confusing) as `HelperUtils.fetchUsernameFromInternet(...)` - you should even get a compiler warning due to this `helper.fetchUsernameFromInternet`.

What's more, instead of `Mockito.mock` to mock static methods you have to use: `@RunWith(...)`, `@PrepareForTest(...)` and then `PowerMockito.mockStatic(...)` - complete example is here: [PowerMockito mock single static method and return object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583202/powermockito-mock-single-static-method-and-return-object)

In other words - mocking static methods (and also constructors) is a bit tricky. Better solution is:

- if you can change `HelperUtils`, make that method non-static and now you can mock `HelperUtils` with the usual `Mockito.mock`
- if you can't change `HelperUtils`, create a wrapper class which delegates to the original `HelperUtils`, but doesn't have `static` methods, and then also use usual `Mockito.mock` (this idea is sometimes called "don't mock types you don't own")

Answer (score 5):

I did this way using **PowerMockito**.

I am using `AppUtils.class`, it contains multiple static methods and functions.

**Static function:**

```
public static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    return target != null && EMAIL_PATTERN.matcher(target).matches();
}
```

**Test case:**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({AppUtils.class})
public class AppUtilsTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(AppUtils.class);

        PowerMockito.when(AppUtils.isValidEmail(anyString())).thenCallRealMethod();
    }

    @Test
    public void testValidEmail() {
        assertTrue(AppUtils.isValidEmail("name@email.com"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testInvalidEmail1() {
        assertFalse(AppUtils.isValidEmail("name@email..com"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testInvalidEmail2() {
        assertFalse(AppUtils.isValidEmail("@email.com"));
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

Add following imports:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
```

Hope this would help you.

Comment: @FazalHussain, I've updated the answer. Please let me know.

Comment: What to do when type is other than String?

Comment: @HarishGyanani You may use `any()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mockito latest version i.e 3.4.+ which allows static mocking

https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#48

Answer (score 0):

Here are some solutions:

- Modify your static method as a non-static method or wrap your static method with a non-static method, and then directly use Mockito to mock the non-static method in the Android Test.
- If you don't want to change any original code, you can try to use a [dexmaker-mockito-inline-extended](https://bintray.com/linkedin/maven/dexmaker-mockito-inline-extended) to mock static methods and final methods in the Android Test. I successfully mocked the static methods with it. Check this
  [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64057104/6238538).
- Use a [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) in the Unit test and then use PowerMock to mock the static methods in the Unit Test.