# Android Unit Testing - method to test returning null

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Method to test:

```
public static String getDeviceName() {
    String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    String model = Build.MODEL;
    if (model.startsWith(manufacturer)) {
        return WordUtils.capitalize(model);
    } else {
        return WordUtils.capitalize(manufacturer) + " " + model;
    }
}
```

test case:

```
@Test
public void testGetDeviceName() throws Exception {
    String deviceNameTest = "device name";
    assertEquals(deviceNameTest, DeviceUtil.getDeviceName());
}
```

Error

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> getDeviceName(DeviceUtil.java:15)
>   DeviceUtilTest.testGetDeviceName(DeviceUtilTest.java:18)
>
> DeviceUtil.getDeviceName() -> returns null

Comment: What are the values for Build.MANUFACTURER and Build.MODEL?

Comment: something like this: Genymotion Samsung Galaxy S8 - 7.0.0 - API 24 - 1440x2960

Comment: You need to debug your test case, it seems that you are missing something in your utility class. Could you also send your util classes?

Comment: on test class: Build.MANUFACTURER and Build.MODEL returns null

Comment: Can you show us the relevant parts of the class `Build`.

Comment: Build is from:  android.os.Build package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not test `getDeviceName()`, `Build.MANUFACTURER` and `Build. MODEL` will return null. Also manufacturer and model are from device, how your IDE can get it?

BTW if you want to test Util class with static method, i suggest you to use 
 `PowerMock` as well or you have to create wrapper class of util for testing.

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074356/how-to-android-unit-test-and-mock-a-static-method

Comment: @SkyWalker no problem. normally I create wrapper class of util class for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the value of the android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER and android.os.Build.MODEL in your test with thee following code:

```kotlin
ReflectionHelpers.setStaticField(android.os.Build::class.java, "MANUFACTURER", "My Manufacturer")
ReflectionHelpers.setStaticField(android.os.Build::class.java, "MODEL", "My Model ")
```

Find below the full piece of code.

```kotlin
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
internal class DeviceInfoManagerImplTest{
    private lateinit var manager: DeviceInfoManagerImpl
    private lateinit var context: Context
    private lateinit var firebaseTokenManager: FirebaseManager
    private lateinit var dispatchers: CoroutineDispatchers

    @BeforeAll
    fun setUp(){
        context = mockk(relaxed = true)
        firebaseTokenManager= mockk()
        dispatchers = spyk()
        manager = DeviceInfoManagerImpl(context,
                firebaseTokenManager,
                dispatchers)

        coEvery { dispatchers.io } returns
                CoroutineDispatchersImpl().io

        coEvery { firebaseTokenManager.getToken() } returns "token"
        ReflectionHelpers.setStaticField(android.os.Build::class.java, "MANUFACTURER", "My Manufacturer")
        ReflectionHelpers.setStaticField(android.os.Build::class.java, "MODEL", "My Model ")

        mockkStatic(Settings.Secure::class)

        every {
            Settings.Secure.getString(context.contentResolver,
                    Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)
        } answers {
            "My ID"
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun test(){
        val deviceInfo = runBlocking { manager.getDeviceInfo() }
        println(deviceInfo.deviceManufacturer)
        println(deviceInfo.deviceUniqueIdentification)
    }
}
```