# Unable to mock static methods using Mockito for instrumentation tests in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I am using `Mockito` framework for mocking objects for writing instrumentation tests. But I am not able to mock static methods using `Mockito`. I know this is not possible using `Mockito` alone and the recommended solution is to use `PowerMock` on top of `Mockito`. But when I use `PowerMock`, it throws the following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Extension API internal error: org.powermock.api.extension.proxyframework.ProxyFrameworkImpl could not be located in classpath.
```

Searching for this exception shows that it is because PowerMock produces .class files but for running instrumentation tests we need to have .dex file. Therefore the solution was to add dexmaker library. Therefore I added the dexmaker library.

```
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
```

But after adding that library, I am getting the below exception at compile time.

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker
    File1: C:\Users\anshul.jain\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.powermock\powermock-api-mockito\1.6.4\fe12509b7e9e49d25131f4155145748a31e42e40\powermock-api-mockito-1.6.4.jar
    File2: C:\Users\anshul.jain\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.dexmaker\dexmaker-mockito\1.2\b99884a4c6ef6335ba376f79aa79632b2421c17c\dexmaker-mockito-1.2.jar
```

I am not able to mock static methods using Mockito. Any solution for this?

Comment: Hey :) Which TestRunner do you use?

Comment: android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

Comment: Try @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

Comment: in Android Studio configuration, I have given AndroidJunitRunner, but for individual tests where I am using PowerMock I am using @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class). I tried using MockitoJunitRunner.class, but still the test case failed with message "Test framework quit unexpectedly"

Comment: Well, the problem is that the libraries use the same class (PowerMock and the dexmaker-mockito). You would need to exclude the class (or maybe the whole package) from one of the libs.

Comment: Wait. In the first solution, did you add the Annotation for the classes you were power-mocking?

Comment: Yes, I am adding @Runwith(PowerMockRunner.class) for the classes where  I am using PowerMock.

Comment: I mean the @PrepareForTest(YourStaticClass.class) annotation. Add it below the TestRunner annotation and try the first solution again

Comment: Yes, PrepareForTest is already below the TestRunner annotation.

Comment: Please try my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64057104/6238538 Hope it helps :)